# Formula for calculating the success chance of this battle?

Tags: probability

I can't figure out the formula to calculate the probability the player will win a battle against an enemy, taking into consideration these variables:

|  | Player | Enemy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Health | 80 | 60 |
| Chance to hit | 45% | 80% |
| Avg. damage dealt by category | 9 | 7 |

It's a turn-based battle so I can tell that, if no one misses a hit, based on their health the player will be dead within 12 turns, and the enemy would take 7 turns. So the player would win. However, I need to take into consideration that some attacks may miss or be blocked (hence the **Chance to hit** percentage).

I've used this formula to calculate a Probability before but, in this case, I have no clue how to obtain the **Number of favorable outcomes** or the **Total number of outcomes**.

Probability = Number of favorable outcomes / Total number of outcomes

Comment: How will player die within 8 turns if no misses? Shouldn’t it take $\left\lceil\frac{80}{9} \right\rceil =9$ or $\left\lceil\frac{80}{7} \right\rceil =12$ hits? (Based on whether “avg. damage” means average damage _by_ the player , or average damage _to_ the player.)

Comment: You're right, I updated the values. "Avg. damage" means damage dealt **by** each.